# iAd into OpenGL

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, sdk, iad

I current have an OpenGL based game and I'm trying to integrate iAd into it.

My current initializer code looks like this

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];
// Now show the status bar, but animate to the style.
[application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

[glView startAnimation];
}
```

So, I've created a `UIViewController` which implements `<ADBannerViewDelegate>` but I'm not sure how to 'connect' the two together. I've tried just adding my `viewController` to the window's subView but no ads display, and it just makes it so none of my taps on the screen are captured.

Comment: Is glView a subview of the app's window? (self.window I assume)?